# Force read on disk with std::ifstream instead of the file cache

Tags: c++, windows, caching, std, ifstream

I have a program that load data from a file using std::ifstream and store the data in a structure. After that, I verify if the data I want was in the file. If it is not, I ask the user to modify the file and press a key. I then reload the file. The problem is that even if the user modified the file, I always get the same data in the file because the file seems to be cache in the application. I've seen that in win32 API, it's possible to use the flag FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING to avoid using a buffered copy when reading a file, but I would like to use that feature with std::ifstream. Is there any way to use the handle created through win32 api with ifstream or anyway to force it directly in std::ifstream ?

Here's a "simplified" code sample:

```
SomeStructure  s = LoadData(fileName);
while(!DataValid(s))
    s = LoadData(fileName);


SomeStructure LoadData(const std::string& fileName)
{
    std::ifstream fileStream;
    while(!OpenFileRead(fileName, fileStream))
    {
        std::cout<<"File not found, please update it";
        fileStream.close();
        //Wait for use input
        std::string dummy;
        std::getline(std::cin, dummy);
    }
    //... Read file, fill structure, and return
    std::string line;   
    while(std::getline(fileStream, line) && line!="")
    {
        //At this point, I can see that line is wrong
        StringArray namedatearray=Utils::String::Split(line, "|");
        assert(namedatearray.size()==2);
        //Add data to my structure ( a map)
     }
     fileStream.close();
     //return structure
}

bool OpenFileRead(const std::string& name, std::fstream& file)
{    
    file.open(name.c_str(), std::ios::in);
    return !file.fail();
}
```

Thanks.

Edit: Of course, it was a mistake because I had two time the same file in two very similar path. Looking at the handle of the file open with process explorer (and not the relative file path made me found it).

Comment: Unbuffered IO has no bearing here.  You either have faulty write code or faulty read code.

Comment: If the problem is caching in the application, as you claim, then unbuffered I/O is not going to help you, because unbuffered I/O means no buffering *in the kernel*. It has no bearing on the application's cached data. And you're unlikely to get `ifstream` to work with an unbuffered handle, because [when you create an object with constraints, you have to make sure everybody who uses the object understands those constraints](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/04/14/9995509.aspx).

Comment: How are you modifying the file? Many things that we think of as "modifying" the file actually don't modify the file at all but  instead *replace* the file with a new, modified file.

Comment: For the write code, well the modification are done with plain old notepad (and saved right after). As for the read part, I've added it in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of thinking that this is due to some kind of "buffering", I would look for the obvious things first.

- Are you sure the user is changing the same file that you're reading?
- Are you certain reloading the data is properly updating your data structure in memory?
- Are you confident that `DataValid()` is doing what you want?

The fact that the OS uses file buffers to increase disk performance is generally not visible from the application level. As long as you're looking at the same file, the OS knows that the user updated the file, and if you reopen it, then you'll see the changed data. If the data never even had a chance to get flushed to disk, that won't affect your application.

Comment: 1) Well, the user is me, and there is only version of the file, so I'm sure I'm changing the good version of the file. As for the rest, after opening my file succesfully, I step in the file line by line and I see that the data is like the old version of the file and not the new one. What makes me think it's due to an application buffering is that if I reload my application, it will read the new version. As for the modification to the file, it's done with notepad (and saved right after). It's effectively kind of a weird that I suffer from such a problem at the application level though...

Comment: Does your application perhaps have another handle to the file open somewhere else? That might help explain why reloading your application works. When your application closes, *all* handles you had open are closed.

Comment: Hum... that's kind of embarassing... When visualizing the handles of my program (with process explorer), I've realize I was now with 2 version of the file in two almost identical path (I had errors while upgrading my local repository to tortoise svn to 1.7 so I had to create a new one and was still using the solution of first repository).

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeJodoin: No worries, it happens to everybody. :)